# jQuery Modal Dialog Not Submitting Form

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, submit, form-submit

After saving my modal content, i have to submit the parent page form..
This is the function on modal:

```
function save() {
  var formData = $("#frmModal").serializeArray();
  $.post('${context}/save.do', formData).done(function(data) {
       if($.trim(data) == "true") {   
            $( "#frmParent" ).submit(); // NOT WORKING
        } else {
            alert("Error");
            return;
        }
   });
}
```

But `$( "#frmParent" ).submit();` isn't working, what's wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `$.trim(data)`?

Comment: Are you receiving any error?

Comment: This is the response of my controller method, returns true if save succeed..

Comment: @CarlosMartins no :(

Comment: You can try to console.log the values of your data inside your if statement to see if you still have the values. It would help to see the form code as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
function save() {
var formData = $("#frmModal").serializeArray();
$.post('${context}/save.do', formData).done(function(data) {
   if($.trim(data) == "true") { 
        console.log(true); //Verify if enter the condition
        formData.submit();
    } else {
        alert("Error");
        return;
    }


 });
```

}

Comment: `formData` is an array...  Other than that, all you added was a console log for your solution.

Comment: It's entering the condition